# StackPanel stop scrolling while over a Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, stackpanel

I've been working on a dynamic StackPanel that implement multiple Controls which is in a ScrollViewer. The problem i am facing is that i can't scroll through my whole StackPanel when my mouse hits a DataGrid. I figured that it's because a DataGrid has a scrolling option itself. I want to know how to disable it. I prefer to create and change my controls programmatically. In the solution, i need to be able to modify the DataGrid and the DataGrid must not stop user from scrolling down and up.

```
<Window x:Class="testscroll.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testscroll"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">

        <StackPanel x:Name="panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

This is my test code

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace testscroll
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel.Children.Clear();


            Label lblTicket = new Label();
            lblTicket.Content = "RT Ticket";
            panel.Children.Add(lblTicket);
            TextBox txtBoxRTTicket = new TextBox();

            txtBoxRTTicket.Text = "test";
            txtBoxRTTicket.MaxLength = 5;
            txtBoxRTTicket.Margin = new Thickness(60, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxRTTicket);

            TextBox txtBoxRTTicketFull = new TextBox();
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name = "txtBoxRTTicketFull";
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Text = "http://mtl-ppapp-rt01/rt/Ticket/Display.html?id=" + "11111";
            //txtBoxRTTicket.TextChanged += TxtBoxRTTicket_TextChanged;
            //txtBoxRTTicketFull.MouseDoubleClick += TextBox_MouseDoubleClick;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.IsReadOnly = true;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Margin = new Thickness(200, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxRTTicketFull);

            Label space1 = new Label();
            space1.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space1);
            Label lblTrackPage = new Label();
            lblTrackPage.Content = "Trac Page";
            panel.Children.Add(lblTrackPage);
            TextBox txtBoxTrackPage = new TextBox();
            txtBoxTrackPage.Text = "test";
            txtBoxTrackPage.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
            txtBoxTrackPage.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            //txtBoxTrackPage.MouseDoubleClick += TextBox_MouseDoubleClick;
            txtBoxTrackPage.Margin = new Thickness(60, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxTrackPage);
            //un espace dans le stackpanel
            Label space2 = new Label();
            space2.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space2);
            //on ajoute le premier tableau concernant le pcb
            DataTable tablePCB = new DataTable();
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("PCB Number");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("CAD Number");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Baan Descriptiion");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Display Description");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Detail Description");
            tablePCB.Rows.Add();
            tablePCB.Rows[0][0] = "000-00000-00";
            string cadNbr = ((string)tablePCB.Rows[0][0]).Substring(3, 6);
            tablePCB.Rows[0][1] = "cad" + cadNbr;
            tablePCB.Rows[0][2] = "test";
            tablePCB.Rows[0][3] = "test";
            tablePCB.Rows[0][4] = "test";
            tablePCB.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            DataGrid dgvPCB = new DataGrid();

            dgvPCB.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dgvPCB.ItemsSource = tablePCB.DefaultView;
            panel.Children.Add(dgvPCB);
            //un espace dans le stackpanel
            Label space3 = new Label();
            space3.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space3);
            //on ajoute le premier tableau concernant les assembly
            DataTable tableAssy = new DataTable();
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Assembly Number");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Schematic Description");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Work Instruction");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Warehouse");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Baan Description");//isreadonly
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Display Description");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Detail Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                tableAssy.Rows.Add();
                tableAssy.Rows[i][0] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][1] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][2] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][3] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][4] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][5] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][6] = "test";
            }
            tableAssy.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            tableAssy.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
            DataGrid dgvAssy = new DataGrid();
            //dgvAssy.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dgvAssy.ItemsSource = tableAssy.DefaultView;

            panel.Children.Add(dgvAssy);

            if (null != panel.FindName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name))
                panel.UnregisterName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name);
            panel.RegisterName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name, txtBoxRTTicketFull);

            Label lblNote = new Label();
            lblNote.Content = "Notes:";

            TextBox txtBoxNotes = new TextBox();
            txtBoxNotes.Text = "test";
            txtBoxNotes.AcceptsReturn = true;
            txtBoxNotes.Height = 300;
            txtBoxNotes.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            txtBoxNotes.MaxHeight = 300;
            txtBoxNotes.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            txtBoxNotes.MaxWidth = 800;
            txtBoxNotes.ScrollToEnd();
            Button btnAddAssembly = new Button();
            btnAddAssembly.Content = "Save changes";
            //btnAddAssembly.Click += ((sender1, e1) => save_click(sender1, e1, txtBoxRTTicket.Text, txtBoxTrackPage.Text, (string)tablePCB.Rows[0][3], (string)tablePCB.Rows[0][4], tableAssy, txtBoxNotes, log));
            panel.Children.Add(btnAddAssembly);

            panel.Children.Add(lblNote);

            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxNotes);
        }
    
    }
}
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: You must have skipped WPF lesson 1; creating your view using XAML

Comment: Why no XAML. If you are generating it during compilation, XAML is both easier to write and look.

Comment: Because the StackPanel change as the user enters value or change the selection some parts of the panel get removed and others are added which make it not possible to code it in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: RESUMED: In order to make a ScrollViewer that is fluid with DataGrid in it, you need to add this function to it.

```
DataGrid dgvAssy = new DataGrid();

dgv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

dgv.PreviewMouseWheel += DgvAssy_PreviewMouseWheel;


private void DgvAssy_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
     scrollviewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollviewer1.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
}
```

EDIT : Found the solution. Check the code, below! The issue is that the datagrid doesn't scroll the scroll viewer. You get the mouse scroll event and scroll the scroll viewer.

**XAML** :

```
<Window x:Class="testscroll.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testscroll"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
            <StackPanel x:Name="panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind** :

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace testscroll
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel.Children.Clear();


            Label lblTicket = new Label();
            lblTicket.Content = "RT Ticket";
            panel.Children.Add(lblTicket);
            TextBox txtBoxRTTicket = new TextBox();

            txtBoxRTTicket.Text = "test";
            txtBoxRTTicket.MaxLength = 5;
            txtBoxRTTicket.Margin = new Thickness(60, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxRTTicket);

            TextBox txtBoxRTTicketFull = new TextBox();
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name = "txtBoxRTTicketFull";
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Text = "http://mtl-ppapp-rt01/rt/Ticket/Display.html?id=" + "11111";
            //txtBoxRTTicket.TextChanged += TxtBoxRTTicket_TextChanged;
            //txtBoxRTTicketFull.MouseDoubleClick += TextBox_MouseDoubleClick;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.IsReadOnly = true;
            txtBoxRTTicketFull.Margin = new Thickness(200, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxRTTicketFull);

            Label space1 = new Label();
            space1.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space1);
            Label lblTrackPage = new Label();
            lblTrackPage.Content = "Trac Page";
            panel.Children.Add(lblTrackPage);
            TextBox txtBoxTrackPage = new TextBox();
            txtBoxTrackPage.Text = "test";
            txtBoxTrackPage.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
            txtBoxTrackPage.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
            //txtBoxTrackPage.MouseDoubleClick += TextBox_MouseDoubleClick;
            txtBoxTrackPage.Margin = new Thickness(60, -25, 0, 0);
            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxTrackPage);
            //un espace dans le stackpanel
            Label space2 = new Label();
            space2.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space2);
            //on ajoute le premier tableau concernant le pcb
            DataTable tablePCB = new DataTable();
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("PCB Number");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("CAD Number");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Baan Descriptiion");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Display Description");
            tablePCB.Columns.Add("Detail Description");
            tablePCB.Rows.Add();
            tablePCB.Rows[0][0] = "000-00000-00";
            string cadNbr = ((string)tablePCB.Rows[0][0]).Substring(3, 6);
            tablePCB.Rows[0][1] = "cad" + cadNbr;
            tablePCB.Rows[0][2] = "test";
            tablePCB.Rows[0][3] = "test";
            tablePCB.Rows[0][4] = "test";
            tablePCB.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
            tablePCB.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            DataGrid dgvPCB = new DataGrid();

            dgvPCB.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dgvPCB.ItemsSource = tablePCB.DefaultView;

            panel.Children.Add(dgvPCB);
            //un espace dans le stackpanel
            Label space3 = new Label();
            space3.Content = "";
            panel.Children.Add(space3);
            //on ajoute le premier tableau concernant les assembly
            DataTable tableAssy = new DataTable();
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Assembly Number");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Schematic Description");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Work Instruction");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Warehouse");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Baan Description");//isreadonly
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Display Description");
            tableAssy.Columns.Add("Detail Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                tableAssy.Rows.Add();
                tableAssy.Rows[i][0] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][1] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][2] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][3] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][4] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][5] = "test";
                tableAssy.Rows[i][6] = "test";
            }
            tableAssy.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            tableAssy.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
            DataGrid dgvAssy = new DataGrid();
            dgvPCB.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
            dgvAssy.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

            dgvAssy.PreviewMouseWheel += DgvAssy_PreviewMouseWheel;
            dgvPCB.PreviewMouseWheel += DgvAssy_PreviewMouseWheel;
            //dgvAssy.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dgvAssy.ItemsSource = tableAssy.DefaultView;

            panel.Children.Add(dgvAssy);

            if (null != panel.FindName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name))
                panel.UnregisterName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name);
            panel.RegisterName(txtBoxRTTicketFull.Name, txtBoxRTTicketFull);

            Label lblNote = new Label();
            lblNote.Content = "Notes:";

            TextBox txtBoxNotes = new TextBox();
            txtBoxNotes.Text = "test";
            txtBoxNotes.AcceptsReturn = true;
            txtBoxNotes.Height = 300;
            txtBoxNotes.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            txtBoxNotes.MaxHeight = 300;
            txtBoxNotes.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            txtBoxNotes.MaxWidth = 800;
            txtBoxNotes.ScrollToEnd();
            Button btnAddAssembly = new Button();
            btnAddAssembly.Content = "Save changes";
            //btnAddAssembly.Click += ((sender1, e1) => save_click(sender1, e1, txtBoxRTTicket.Text, txtBoxTrackPage.Text, (string)tablePCB.Rows[0][3], (string)tablePCB.Rows[0][4], tableAssy, txtBoxNotes, log));
            panel.Children.Add(btnAddAssembly);

            panel.Children.Add(lblNote);

            panel.Children.Add(txtBoxNotes);

        }

        private void DgvAssy_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            scrollviewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollviewer1.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty doesn't exist in WPF 
what you are proposing me is :
myDataGrid.VerticalScrollBarVisibility= ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
But that is not what i want to achieve. I want to remove the scrolling event over the grid when my mouse is passing over the grid when i am scrolling my ScrollViewer

Comment: Who told the HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty is not available in WPF?

It is available for a datagrid. Your question was on how to disable the scrolling for datagrid, right?

Comment: i made an edit to show you that the HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty is not accessible by SetValue. But this is not my question. I don't want to hide the visibility of the scrollbar. I want don't want my grid to not interfere with the ScrollViewer's scrolling. If you try my code and you put your mouse over a DataGrid, you can't scroll the scrollViewer. I dont want this to happen.

Comment: I tried with your code. As you told it is true. It is quiet impossible to do what you need. But I am seeing such an issue for the first time. For the time being set the vertical scroll bar visibility to visibile so that user can scroll the area of scrollbar to go down or drag it. 

Please check edit part of my answer.

I will check and come up with a solution soon.